# Populate Dropdown based on another Dropdown Using Ajax, jQuery and Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I just wanna ask how to populate a dropdown based on another dropdown's value.

When I select a Campaign, it will show the names of the people that are in that Campaign in another dropdown but the value must be the id of the name.

Here is my Model

```
function get_agents($campaign_id)
{
    $campaign_id1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id,trim($campaign_id));
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tbl_employee.emp_id, CONCAT(tbl_applicant.fname, ' ', tbl_applicant.lname) AS fullname FROM tbl_applicant INNER JOIN tbl_employee ON tbl_employee.apid=tbl_applicant.apid INNER JOIN tbl_account ON tbl_employee.acc_id=tbl_account.acc_id WHERE tbl_account.acc_id='".$campaign_id1."'");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Here is my Controller

```
public function getAgents()
{
   $campaign_id = $this->input->post('campaign_id');
   $this->KudosModel->get_agents($campaign_id);
   echo $result;
}
```

Here is my AJAX

```
$('#addCampaign').on('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data : 'campaign_id='+ $('#addCampaign').val(),
            url : 'controller/method',
            success : function(data){
                $('#anyname').val(data);
            }
        });
    }); //I dont know what to do here
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You are not assigning $result to anything in your controller.

Comment: You haven't mentioned how the code fails.

Comment: Nothing comes out on the anyname dropdown

Comment: Have you tried console.log()?

Comment: `success : function(data){
               console.log(data);
            }` see what comes out in your console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need some manipulation in controller like-

```
public function getAgents()
{
   $campaign_id = $this->input->post('campaign_id');
   $employees = $this->KudosModel->get_agents($campaign_id);
   /*
   foreach($employees as $employee)
   {
       echo "<option value='".$employee->emp_id."'>".$employee->fullname."</option>"
   }*/
  // for json  
  $employeesList = [];
  foreach($employees as $employee)
  {
     array_push($employeeList,array('emp_id'=>$employee->emp_id,'fullnme'=>$employee->fullname));
  }
  echo json_encode($employeeList, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}
```

now in ajax success function-

```
success : function(data){
        // anyname should be the id of the dropdown
        // $('#anyname').append(data);
        // for json 
        $json = JSON.parse(data);
        // empty your dropdown 
        $('#dropdownId').empty();
        $.each($json,function(key,value){
            $('#dropdownId').append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
        })

}
```

Comment: feel free to ask.. if solved please accept as correct answer

Comment: When I try to alert the data it shows <option value='*the id*'>*the name*</option> but it doesnt populate the other dropdown.

Comment: what is the id of the second dropdownlist, you are close to solution, i will change my answer

Comment: Got it bro. Turns out i placed the wrong id of the data. Haha. Thank you man! You're a blessing. I could hug you right now hahaha

Comment: you are welcome ... you can also use-  `$('#anyname').html(data);`, every time it will remove all data and add new list

Comment: Wait man. There is a problem. Turns out when i change the option in the first dropdown, it appends the output of the first selected option to the second dropdown.

Comment: you can use html instead of append.. i wrote in comment.. thanks

Comment: This works, but i'm not sure returning the complete HTML is a good solution, you should never play with your front end in your backend. It's supose to be the other way around. The backend returns data, the frontend plays with it.

Comment: In your case you are not returning data, you are simply returning the whole HTML. the data is not manipulable.

Comment: if you want to manipulate it in front end then you need to make use of json_encode in php and loop in front end  over response data

Comment: how do i add an empty value in this?

Comment: It really is a bad idea using this since I cant manipulate the data on the update part of the application. Can someone help me how to assign the json encoded data to the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through your data and add options to your second Select

```
$('#addCampaign').on('change', function(){
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    data : 'campaign_id='+ $('#addCampaign').val(),
    url : 'controller/method',
    success : function(data){
        //data returns your name, iterate through it and add the name to another select
        $.each(data, function($index, $value) {
            $('#secondSelect').append($("<option></option>").val($value.id).html($value.name));
        });
    }
});
});
```

One thing, if you need a listener on your second `<select>` lets say `on('click')`, you need to add it back once you populated it. If not, Jquery won't recognize the new values.

#### Edit

Also, as @PersyJack stated, you need to asign the variable `$result` to something if you want to return it.

```
public function getAgents()
{
    $campaign_id = $this->input->post('campaign_id');
    $result = $this->KudosModel->get_agents($campaign_id);
    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: How do I assign it to return it? Will this work?

$data['agents'] = $this->KudosModel->get_agents($campaign_id);
$this->load->view('kudoslist', $data);

Comment: Well yea, your method `get_agents()` returns your query result. But you never use them. they just stay there in the void, 'till the end of times. You need to asign them to a variable if you want to returns them to your ajax request, in your case you are returning the variable `$result` so you need to asign them to `$result`

Comment: You don't have to use a view. You need to return data to your Ajax,

Comment: I tried what Veshraj Joshi suggested and turns out it returns this -> <option value='*the id*'>*the name*</option> but it doesnt populate the dropdown. Any suggestion?

Comment: well in this case, you need to remove what's inside the `append()` which is `$("<option></option>").val($value.id).html($value.name)` and the for around it and just `append()` the data

Comment: But since you are using his version, you should follow what he said in his answer.